# Newer Shimano R7000 pedals having smaller contact area than older R5800?

Tags: shimano, pedals

I was comparing Shimano PD-5800 and the newer PR-7000 SPD-SL pedals. Judging from the metal contact plate on them, the newer model seems to have a far smaller contact surface area.

Is this correct judgment or are the metal plates only part of contact area?

PD-5800 SPD-SL pedals-

[image]

Newer PD-7000 SPD-SL pedals-

[image]

Comment: The premise of the question is: Does cleat-to-pedal contact area even matter? It’s not like your foot is only touching those small areas, there is a sturdy cleat and a carbon (or glass) fiber sole in-between. It’s important that the shoe doesn’t tilt, and for that a reinforced support to the very left and right like in the PD-7000 works best.

Comment: @Michael Its a question for understanding the thing, not taking a decision. I've already purchased R7000 pedals. this is just something I found interesting as an observation and would like to improve my understanding about it.

Answer (score 3):

The metal plates are only part of the contact area. In my opinion the 5700 pedals are SO good, you can’t go wrong with either model.   If cost is a factor you will get years of excellent performance and durability from both.

There is a smaller rectangular raised section between the metal contact plates that also contacts the cleats.

Comment: So what else consistutes the contact area?